# Generalization of functions which returns the value of one of arguments

Tags: functions, terminology

If there is a name for a function which return value is limited to one of its arguments? Examples of such functions are 'min' and 'max'.

Comment: Maybe "selection" function.

Comment: In computability theory, they are called [Projection functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function).

Comment: Projection functions are close to what I have in mind. Although they usually fixed like $\pi_1$. In my case, the function could project different arguments depending on their values.